# Build.xml Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: java, ant, build-tools

I am trying to create L2j server (Interlude) server. However when I'm trying to compile the server pack file I get into trouble.

When I run `build.xml` as Ant build I'm getting

> Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

**Error log**

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build.xml
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build
init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build\classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build\dist\login
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build\dist\gameserver
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 1213 source files to C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build\classes
    [javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_171). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
    [javac] java.lang.NullPointerException
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.getPathEntries(Locations.java:149)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.getPathEntries(Locations.java:134)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.access$000(Locations.java:71)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.computePath(Locations.java:617)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.lazy(Locations.java:643)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations$BootClassPathLocationHandler.getLocation(Locations.java:577)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.Locations.getLocation(Locations.java:678)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getLocation(JavacFileManager.java:803)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.list(JavacFileManager.java:617)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:2750)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:2446)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.access$000(ClassReader.java:76)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$1.complete(ClassReader.java:240)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:574)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.visitTopLevel(Enter.java:300)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:518)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:258)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.classEnter(Enter.java:272)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:486)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    [javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:56)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:58)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1395)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1121)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    [javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    [javac]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:142)

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\tauti\git\l2j_server\L2J_Server\build.xml:51: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 29 seconds
```

**Build.xml**

```
</description>
    <property name="src" location="java" />
    <property name="lib" location="lib" />
    <property name="build" location="build" />
    <property name="build.classes" location="${build}/classes" />
    <property name="build.dist" location="${build}/dist" />
    <property name="build.dist.login" location="${build.dist}/login" />
    <property name="build.dist.game" location="${build.dist}/gameserver" />
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="c3p0-0.9.2-pre1.jar" />
            <include name="bsf.jar" />
            <include name="bsh-2.0b4.jar" />
            <include name="commons-logging-1.1.jar" />
            <include name="jython.jar" />
            <include name="javolution-5.5.1.jar" />
            <include name="mchange-commons-0.2.jar" />
            <include name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" />
            <include name="mmocore.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="init" depends="clean" description="Create the output directories.">
        <mkdir dir="${build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.classes}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.login}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}" />
    </target>
    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source.">
        <javac destdir="${build.classes}" optimize="on" debug="on" source="1.8" target="1.8" nowarn="off" includeantruntime="false" deprecation="yes">
            <src path="${src}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint" />
        </javac>
    </target>
    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Create the jar file">
        <jar destfile="${build}/l2jserver.jar">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes}" />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="net.sf.l2j.Server" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". bsf.jar bsh-2.0b4.jar commons-logging-1.1.jar c3p0-0.9.2-pre1.jar jython.jar mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar javolution-5.5.1.jar mchange-commons-0.2.jar mmocore.jar" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.login}">
            <fileset dir="${build}">
                <include name="l2jserver.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}">
            <fileset dir="${build}">
                <include name="l2jserver.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="build" depends="jar">
        <copy todir="${build.dist.login}">
            <fileset dir="${src}">
                <include name="log.cfg" />
                <include name="banned_ip.cfg" />
                <include name="console.cfg" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}">
            <fileset dir="${src}">
                <include name="log.cfg" />
                <include name="console.cfg" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.login}">
            <fileset dir="${src}/../lib">
                <include name="c3p0-0.9.2-pre1.jar" />
                <include name="mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" />
                <include name="javolution-5.5.1.jar" />
                <include name="mmocore.jar" />
                <include name="mchange-commons-0.2.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}">
            <fileset dir="${src}/../lib">
                <include name="*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist}">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}">
                <include name="changes.txt" />
                <include name="LICENSE.txt" />
                <include name="README.txt" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist}">
            <fileset dir="${src}/../lib">
                <include name="*LICENSE*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.login}">
            <fileset dir="dist">
                <include name="startAccountManager.*" />
                <include name="startSQLAccountManager.*" />
                <include name="LoginServer_loop.sh" />
                <include name="startLoginServer.*" />
                <include name="RegisterGameServer.*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}">
            <fileset dir="dist">
                <include name="GameServer_loop.sh" />
                <include name="startGameServer.*" />
                <include name="hibernate.cfg.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <fixcrlf srcdir="${build.dist.game}" eol="lf" eof="remove" includes="**/*.sh">
        </fixcrlf>
        <fixcrlf srcdir="${build.dist.login}" eol="lf" eof="remove" includes="**/*.sh">
        </fixcrlf>
        <fixcrlf srcdir="${build.dist.game}" eol="crlf" eof="remove" includes="**/*.bat">
        </fixcrlf>
        <fixcrlf srcdir="${build.dist.login}" eol="crlf" eof="remove" includes="**/*.bat">
        </fixcrlf>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/log" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.login}/log" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/hibernate-mapping" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/config" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.login}/config" />
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}/config">
            <fileset dir="java/config">
                <include name="*.properties" />
                <exclude name="loginserver.properties" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${build.dist.login}/config">
            <fileset dir="java/config">
                <include name="loginserver.properties" />
                <include name="telnet.properties" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/data" />
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}/data">
            <fileset dir="data">
                <include name="*.csv" />
                <include name="*.txt" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/data/geodata" />
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}/data/geodata">
            <fileset dir="data/geodata">
                <include name="*.txt" />
                <include name="*.l2j" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <mkdir dir="${build.dist.game}/data/pathnode" />
        <copy todir="${build.dist.game}/data/pathnode">
            <fileset dir="data/pathnode">
                <include name="*.txt" />
                <include name="*.pn" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <zip destfile="${build}/L2J_Server.zip" basedir="${build.dist}" />
    </target>
    <target name="clean" description="Remove the output directories">
        <delete dir="${build}" />
    </target>
</project>
```

The 50-55 lines would be:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source.">
        <javac destdir="${build.classes}" optimize="on" debug="on" source="1.8" target="1.8" nowarn="off" includeantruntime="false" deprecation="yes">
            <src path="${src}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint" />
        </javac>
```

If I run another (very similar) `build.xml` I get almost the same error it directs me to different line (89) in that build lines 88-90 are:

```
<target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compile the source.">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" destdir="${build.classes}" compiler="javac1.8" debug="false" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" includeantruntime="false" source="1.8" target="1.8" />
    </target>
```

I am using JDK 1.8.0_171, as the newer ones didn't have tools.jar and I got different error which I wasn't able to solve (with this JDK I was able to run another build (L2j server datapack).

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Below solution worked for me, hope it helps someone else

Eclipse -> Ant tab -> Right click on `build.xml` -> Run As -> **External Tools Configurations**... -> **JRE** tab -> Runtime JRE: -> Select "Run in the same JRE as the workspace" -> Apply and Run